# Display problems with graphic cards

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, acer-aspire, ati-mobility-radeon, intel-core-i3

I've got an **Acer Aspire 4820TG** Laptop
with internal Intel & ATI graphics

My Harddrive crashed recently and i lost all my software for my ATI GPU..
I managed to retrieve all of the software and also got the **ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 1GB** graphics card working again.

Since installing this software my pc runs 2 displays (one for each GPU i guess) when i only have one physical display though. I have tried the "show desktop on display 2 only" (which is my ATI GPU) but when i do this my screen turns completely black. Also when i disable my intel GPU i have to restart the PC and enable it in BIOS mode again...

Any suggestions how i can run both (or maybe only the ATI GPU) on one display?